# Logging with MSBuild does not work with checked out files in BATCH

Tags: file, batch-file, logging, build, msbuild

I have the problem that logging is not made when rebuilding a solution with checked out files. I clearly did not understand what is going wrong. So I decided to ask the community.

I have two different solutions, but I want to use the check out files solution which currently does not work.

1. The solution should get the latest files of a BuildDrop.
2. Check out a core directory from the solution.
3. Copy the BuildDrop files to the core directory.
4. Build the solution with the new core.
5. **(log into log files while rebuild)**
6. Checkin the new core.

**Solution without checkout (works):**

```
@echo off
REM Pfad in denen die Build Drops liegen
set MAINPATH=\\devteamx\BuildDrops\MAIN

REM Pfad in denen die Custom Solutions (Parent) liegen
set CUSTOMPATH=C:\Sources\RECY6\CUSTOM

REM Ausgabe Pfad für Custom dll's
set OUTDIR=C:\Sources\CustomRelease

rd %OUTDIR% /s /q
set ERRORLEVEL=
set neueste=
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir %MAINPATH% /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET neueste=%%i
    GOTO :end
)
:end
set MAINPATH=%MAINPATH%\%neueste%\x86\Release
echo Latest Builddrop of Main is in %MAINPATH%
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k %MAINPATH% %OUTDIR%\

set COREPATH=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%s in ('dir %CUSTOMPATH% /b /ad') do (
    call :Task %%s
)

echo Rebuild of Custom Solutions succeed pause exit

:Showerror
echo Build error occurred in %1
pause
exit

:Task %1
set COREPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%1\RECY\Core
set SLNPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%1\RECY
set ISCUSTOMBUILD=True
echo Corepath of %1 is %COREPATH%
echo %SLNPATH%
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k %MAINPATH% %COREPATH%
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
call %msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe /t:Rebuild %SLNPATH%\RECY.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=%OUTDIR% /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile="CustomDllRelease_%1_%date%.log"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :Showerror %1
set msBuildDir=
echo CustomSolution: %1
```

**Solution with checkout (does not work):**

```
@echo off
REM Pfad in denen die Build Drops liegen
set MAINPATH=\\devteamx\BuildDrops\MAIN

REM Pfad in denen die Custom Solutions (Parent) liegen
set CUSTOMPATH=C:\Sources\RECY6\CUSTOM

REM Ausgabe Pfad für Custom dll's
set OUTDIR=C:\Sources\CustomRelease

REM Visual Studio Version mit tf
set TFPFAD=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

REM Tf Command get Method um die letzten Aenderungen abzurufen
pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" get "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive

rd %OUTDIR% /s /q
set ERRORLEVEL=
set neueste=
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir %MAINPATH% /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET neueste=%%i
    GOTO :end
)
:end
set MAINPATH=%MAINPATH%\%neueste%\x86\Release
echo Latest Builddrop of Main is in %MAINPATH%

set COREPATH=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%s in ('dir %CUSTOMPATH% /b /ad') do (
    call :Task %%s
)

xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k %MAINPATH% %OUTDIR%\
REM pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%"
REM "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" undo "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive /noprompt
echo Rebuild of Custom Solutions succeed
pause
exit

:Showerror
pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%\%1"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" undo "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive /noprompt
echo Build error occurred in %1
pause
exit

:Task %1
REM Tf Command Checkout Files
pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%\%1"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkout "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%1/RECY/Core" /recursive
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :Showerror %1
set COREPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%1\RECY\Core
set SLNPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%1\RECY
set ISCUSTOMBUILD=True
echo Corepath of %1 is %COREPATH%
echo %SLNPATH%
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k %MAINPATH% %COREPATH%
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
call %msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe /t:Rebuild %SLNPATH%\RECY.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=%OUTDIR% /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=CustomDllRelease_%1_%date%.log
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :Showerror %1
set msBuildDir=
pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%\%1"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkin "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%1/RECY/Core" /force /recursive /noprompt /comment:"Custom dll Build Check-In %1 %date%" /override:"Automated Build Process"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :Showerror %1
echo CustomSolution: %1
```

Comment: Does your log file name contain spaces?  If so, add quotations around the logfile name in the second script, like it has in the first script. `logfile="CustomDllRelease_%1_%date%.log"`

Comment: I already tried this... And no the log file does not contain any spaces -.-

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easy to answer as we cannot run the batch file with first line changed from `@echo off` to `@echo on` to see what happens on execution of both batch files.

I compared the 2 batch code blocks. I do not understand why the line

```
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k %MAINPATH% %OUTDIR%\
```

is in first, working batch file above the loop calling `Task` as subroutine while in the second, not working batch file the same command is below the loop after build finished.

**Could this be the reason for not working second batch file?**

It is always more safe to use double quotes on `set` as it can be seen below to avoid that a not visible trailing whitespace character is appended to a string assigned to an environment variable resulting in a not working command sequence.

And I prefer usage of `cd /D ...` instead of `pushd` if `popd` is never used to restore previous working directory and all directories to change to are on a local drive.

Further I prefer usage of parameter `/i` on using `xcopy` if the target is a directory and might not exist, or as in this case definitely does not exist.

Below is your second batch file with the modifications as explained above and some additional changes like passing directory name via an environment variable to subroutine `Task`.

As I could not test it, I don't know if this version of your batch file works, or at least does not contain a syntax error.

```
@echo off
REM Path containing the build drops
set "MAINPATH=\\devteamx\BuildDrops\MAIN"

REM Parent path of the custom solutions
set "CUSTOMPATH=C:\Sources\RECY6\CUSTOM"

REM Output path for the custom DLLs
set "OUTDIR=C:\Sources\CustomRelease"

REM Path to Visual Studion with console application tf
set "TFPFAD=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"

REM Execute tf with method get to get newest changes
cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" get "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive

rd "%OUTDIR%" /s /q
set NEWEST=
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir "%MAINPATH%" /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET "NEWEST=%%i"
    GOTO end
)
:end
set "MAINPATH=%MAINPATH%\%NEWEST%\x86\Release"
echo Latest build drop of main is in %MAINPATH%
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k /i "%MAINPATH%" "%OUTDIR%"

set COREPATH=
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%CUSTOMPATH%" /b /ad') do (
    set "SOLUTION=%%s"
    call :Task
)

echo Rebuild of custom solutions succeeded.
pause
exit

:Showerror
cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" undo "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive /noprompt
echo Build error occurred in %SOLUTION%
pause
exit

:Task
REM Execute tf to check out the files
cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkout "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%SOLUTION%/RECY/Core" /recursive
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
set "COREPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%\RECY\Core"
set "SLNPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%\RECY"
set "ISCUSTOMBUILD=True"
echo Core path of %SOLUTION% is %COREPATH%
echo %SLNPATH%
xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k /i "%MAINPATH%" "%COREPATH%"
set "msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
call "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" /t:Rebuild "%SLNPATH%\RECY.sln" /p:Configuration=Release "/p:OutDir=%OUTDIR%" "/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=CustomDllRelease_%SOLUTION%_%DATE%.log"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
set msBuildDir=
cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
"%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkin "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%SOLUTION%/RECY/Core" /force /recursive /noprompt "/comment:Custom dll Build Check-In %SOLUTION% %DATE%" "/override:Automated Build Process"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
echo CustomSolution: %SOLUTION%
```

Comment: Yes the 2th batch file is quite different. I discovered that i need the files overriden after the build so that i can be sure they were right and the from the latest. I dont know if cd will work on a network drive. I remember i have got problems with cd in this case. And the batch is working fine its just the logging made by the ms build which does not work .... But thanks i will try this out maybe it magically appears to work.

Comment: I tried it out but still no logging is made .... i called popd in case the logging files are saved in a different dir caused by some cd or pushd .....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/wea2sca5(v=vs.90).aspx is some information about msbuild.exeAnd yes echo on gotta helped me the instance of the filelogger could not be load .... but why ... the filelogger is the same as the one in the other file. I already created an own dir for the batch and its logs

Answer (score 0):

I got it! 
I have to set the current directory to the dir where the batch is
delete quotations 
and use another filelogger

```
    @echo on
    REM Path containing the build drops
    set "MAINPATH=C:\BuildDrops\MAIN"

    REM Parent path of the custom solutions
    set "CUSTOMPATH=C:\Sources\RECY6\CUSTOM"

    REM Output path for the custom DLLs
    set "OUTDIR=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Deploy"

    REM Path to Visual Studion with console application tf
    set "TFPFAD=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

    REM Custom dll Path
    set "LOGPATH=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\RECY CustomDeployment"

    REM Execute tf with method get to get newest changes
    cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%"
    "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" get "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive

    rd "%OUTDIR%" /s /q
    set NEWEST=
    FOR /F %%i IN ('dir "%MAINPATH%" /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
        SET "NEWEST=%%i"
        GOTO end
    )
    :end
    set "MAINPATH=%MAINPATH%\%NEWEST%\x86\Release"
    echo Latest build drop of main is in %MAINPATH%

    set COREPATH=
    for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%CUSTOMPATH%" /b /ad') do (
        set "SOLUTION=%%s"
        call :Task
    )


    xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k /i "%MAINPATH%" "%OUTDIR%"
    REM pushd "%CUSTOMPATH%"
    REM "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" undo "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive /noprompt
    echo Rebuild of custom solutions succeeded.
    pause
    exit

    :Showerror
    cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
    "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" undo "$/RECY6/CUSTOM" /recursive /noprompt
    echo Build error occurred in %SOLUTION%
    pause
    exit

    :Task
    REM Execute tf to check out the files
    cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
    "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkout "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%SOLUTION%/RECY/Core" /recursive
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
    set "COREPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%\RECY\Core"
    set "SLNPATH=%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%\RECY"
    set "ISCUSTOMBUILD=True"
    echo Core path of %SOLUTION% is %COREPATH%
    echo %SLNPATH%
    xcopy /s /e /v /y /r /k "%MAINPATH%" "%COREPATH%"
    cd /D %LOGPATH%
    set "msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
    call "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" /t:Rebuild "%SLNPATH%\RECY.sln" /p:Configuration=Release "/p:OutDir=%OUTDIR%" /fileLogger /flp:logfile=CustomDllRelease_%SOLUTION%_%DATE%.log
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
    set msBuildDir=
    cd /D "%CUSTOMPATH%\%SOLUTION%"
    "%TFPFAD%\tf.exe" checkin "$/RECY6/CUSTOM/%SOLUTION%/RECY/Core" /force /recursive /noprompt "/comment:Custom dll Build Check-In %SOLUTION% %DATE%" "/override:Automated Build Process"
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Showerror
    echo CustomSolution: %SOLUTION%
```